# FullCalendar v2.6.1 - Customizing vertical axis times

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to designate a custom time interval for the vertical axis in FullCalendar.

I know I can set slotDuration to a certain value but I need to be able to set different values (times) for the slots.

I have a database which details what times should appear on the calendar so, ideally, I'd like to use these values to populate the times on the vertical axis

The times I'm trying to show look like this.

2:00pm - Booked
2:15pm - Closed
2:22pm - Open
2:35pm - Open
2:40pm - Closed
And so on. [This image shows what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAIZw.png)

Anyone know if this is possible? Image attached detailing what I'm trying to achieve.[This image shows what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAIZw.png)

Thank you!

Comment: Also, I could create the calendar with slotDuration: 00:01:00 and then remove those times which don't match what appears in my database (via ajax call).  I'm just not certain where I could do this.  On EventRender?